# What is the role of IIS

Tags: iis, webserver

I was look through some sample questions in a Microsoft certification exam. I came across this question which I answered wrong and cant understand why...

---

**Question**

```
2. An employee at a reputable ISP tells Maxim that they use Windows Server and that he needs 
to understand the basics of Internet Information Services (IIS). Which of the following is NOT 
a role of IIS?
  a. to deliver HTML documents to web browsers
  b. to enable server-side scripting, such as ASP.NET
  c. to enable client-side scripting, such as JavaScript
```

[This question is presented here on the 37th slide](ftp://ftp.certiport.com/Marketing/MTA/docs/MTA_SSG_SoftDev_individual_without_crop.pdf)

To me, the awswer seems to be `c` since IIS has nothing to do with client side script other than send it to the client but the slide says the answer is `b`.

Can someone explain why its `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slide's answer is faulty, which is obvious from the explanation in **Essential details** on the same slide as the answer (#38):

> IIS (Internet Information Services) is a part of Windows Server that
>   delivers content such as web pages by using HTTP over the World Wide
>   Web.
>
> • IIS provides functionality essential for deploying ASP.NET web
>   applications.
>   • IIS also supports other server-side scripting, such
>   as PHP.

From this it is clear that the correct answer is indeed `c` and that this was an error in the *Answers* section.

Comment: Check the answer as accepted if it helped you, to make it clear for others who search the same topic.

Comment: yea I forgot about it. It first said I needed to wait 6 minutes before accepting. Thanks for reminding me!